# navigate between widgets using arrows in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, qwidget, qtgui

I'm working on UI using QT. The ui is simple, it's app based like IPhone or Android. Say there are 9 items (3 rows x 3 cols).

What I want to do is to navigate between widgets using arrow keys. 
If the focus is in [row 1,col 1] and I press down arrow, I want it to go to [row 2, col 1]
another example.
If the focus is in [row 2,col 3] and I press up arrow, I want it to go to [row 1, col 3]

But the current behavior is up and right always go to next widget and down and left always go to previous widget.

Is there any way to do this in qt? or I need to create some algorithm to do this?

Thanks

Comment: All 9 items are visible at the same time?

Comment: install an event handler with a switch, and set the focus as needed depending on which key is pressed

Comment: @Samoth: naturally, but it would be more useful to give some code for more details, even if pseudo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: See amazing example at the end.

Basic Widget focus navigation starts out with this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/focus.html

Arrow navigation is available easily with a `QTableView`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#navigation

If you can get your widgets to work inside the structure of a `QTableView`, then you don't need to implement it, it comes as a part of the wrapper/view widget.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

Model View programming does have a learning curve, but it is worth while to learn and use.

But this is by no means the only way to accomplish this.

There are event filters, key events, focus events that can be leveraged to accomplish this feat without using a `QTableView` or `QTableWidget`.  But figuring out the best way to do it without making it look messy may take some time.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#notify

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq11-events.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfocusevent.html

Key events are set to the item with the focus, and if they ignore the event it propagates up to its parent.  So as long as your items in your table/grid ignore the key events having to do with the arrow keys, then you could have your parent widget listen for the key events and handle them appropriately.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#FocusReason-enum

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#focusWidget

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Fully working example in `QGraphicsView` of what you want to do:

```
Qt Creator > Welcome tab > Examples > Pad Navigator Example
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-padnavigator.html

Here is the relevant code from the example:

```
// Enable key navigation using state transitions
for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        QState *state = stateGrid[y][x];
        QKeyEventTransition *rightTransition = new QKeyEventTransition(this, QEvent::KeyPress,
                                                                       Qt::Key_Right, state);
        QKeyEventTransition *leftTransition = new QKeyEventTransition(this, QEvent::KeyPress,
                                                                      Qt::Key_Left, state);
        QKeyEventTransition *downTransition = new QKeyEventTransition(this, QEvent::KeyPress,
                                                                      Qt::Key_Down, state);
        QKeyEventTransition *upTransition = new QKeyEventTransition(this, QEvent::KeyPress,
                                                                    Qt::Key_Up, state);
        rightTransition->setTargetState(stateGrid[y][(x + 1) % columns]);
        leftTransition->setTargetState(stateGrid[y][((x - 1) + columns) % columns]);
        downTransition->setTargetState(stateGrid[(y + 1) % rows][x]);
        upTransition->setTargetState(stateGrid[((y - 1) + rows) % rows][x]);
```

EDIT:
Amazing example using `QShortcut`s and a `QGridLayout` and a bunch of `QPushButton`s:

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QShortcut>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    m_grid = new QGridLayout;
    for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            m_grid->addWidget(new QPushButton("Row " + QString::number(r)
                                              + ", Col " + QString::number(c)),
                              r, c);
        }
    }
    this->setLayout(m_grid);

    m_grid->itemAtPosition(1, 1)->widget()->setFocus();

    this->setStyleSheet("QPushButton::focus{ background: black; color: white;}");

    // only works for in Qt for Embedded Linux, Symbian and Windows CE only.
    //    QApplication::setNavigationMode(Qt::NavigationModeKeypadDirectional);

    QShortcut * shortcut;
    shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Up),this,
                             SLOT(on_up()));
    shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Down),this,
                             SLOT(on_down()));
    shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Left),this,
                             SLOT(on_left()));
    shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Right),this,
                             SLOT(on_right()));
}

void Widget::on_up()
{
    moveFocus(0, -1);
}

void Widget::on_down()
{
    moveFocus(0, 1);
}

void Widget::on_left()
{
    moveFocus(-1, 0);
}

void Widget::on_right()
{
    moveFocus(1, 0);
}

void Widget::moveFocus(int dx, int dy)
{
    if(qApp->focusWidget() == 0)
        return;
    int idx = m_grid->indexOf(qApp->focusWidget());
    if(idx == -1)
        return;
    int r, c, rowSpan, colSpan;
    m_grid->getItemPosition(idx, &r, &c, &rowSpan, &colSpan);
    QLayoutItem* layoutItem = m_grid->itemAtPosition(r + dy, c + dx);
    if(layoutItem == 0)
        return;
    layoutItem->widget()->setFocus();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    QGridLayout * m_grid;
public slots:
    void on_up();
    void on_down();
    void on_left();
    void on_right();
    void moveFocus(int dx, int dy);
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Wow, more than half of the post is just links. It would be better to actually give some inline solution, even if just pseudo-code, rather than jumping from link-to-link.

Comment: What do you think @LaszloPapp ?  A little better?  :-)

Answer (score -1):

To enable keypad navigation, build Qt with QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION defined.
https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qapplication.html#keypadNavigationEnabled